# How to iterate over bash sqlcmd output

Tags: linux, bash, sqlcmd

I have a SQLCMD in linux bash that im getting the results of a SELECT, how can i iterate over each line, and be able to pick out specific columns so that i can use them to run a bash command on

I currently doa SELECT and output to csv file, which works OK, but i would rather find a way that does not export, as permissions are in play, and i need to run all fully withing the one script

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlcmd -S DB_string -d DB -U USERNAME -P PASSWORD -Q \
"SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT * FROM dbo.microiopenvpn WHERE mode='create' ORDER BY id" -o "sqloutputCheckCreate.csv" -W -w 1024 -s"," -h-1
line_no=0
file=sqloutputCheckCreate.csv
line_no=$(awk '{x++} END {print x}' $file)
echo $line_no

#rowCount= sqloutputCheckCreate.csv | wc -l

if [ $line_no > 0 ]; then
    echo "SQL Has Entries"
    while IFS="," read -r d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6; do

      if [ -e "/etc/openvpn/clients/$d6.ovpn" ]; then
            echo "$d6 File exists"
            sqlcmd -S DB_string -d DB -U USERNAME -P PASSWORD -Q \ -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON UPDATE dbo.microiopenvpn SET mode='valid' WHERE id='$d1'" < /dev$                echo "Database Updated - Successfully"
      else
            echo "$d6 does not exist - Action Creation Script of $d6"
            ./executecreate.sh
      fi

    done < sqloutputCheckCreate.csv    
 else
    echo "Nothing there"
  fi

cp /dev/null sqloutputCheckCreate.csv
```

the above works when exporting to external csav file, but I need to put sql export into variable and loop over that - so nothing external - ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
sqlcmd ... | while IFS="," read -r d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6
do
    :# stuff
done
```

or, alternatively:

```
while IFS="," read -r d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6
do
    :# stuff
done < <(sqlcmd ...)
```

Comment: that works perfectly - thanks for that. ok so when i run it only does 1 row, even if the query should take at least 2 rows, it does not goto the next row, when i run it again it picks the next row up , on the sql connection i do have -s "~", so i know what seperates the columns - any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Read Single Column into Bash Loop

```
SQLCMD="sqlcmd -h -1 -S $SERVERNAME -U $USERNAME -P $PASSWORD -d $DBNAME -Q"
for ctry in $($SQLCMD " SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT ctry_cd FROM country ")
do
    echo "Processing for Ctry: $ctry "
done
```

Read Multiple Columns into Bash Loop

```
$SQLCMD " SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT ctry_cd, ctry_nm FROM country " | while read -r ctry_cd ctry_nm
do
     echo "Processing for Ctry: $ctry_cd Name: $ctry_nm "
done
```